# How to align primefaces menubar content to be right-aligned

Tags: css, primefaces

I want to override the default align of primefaces menubar component to be right-aligned. Specifically I want a certain sub-menu, not all of the sub-menus of that menubar.

Which CSS class do I have to override to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

What I want to achieve:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding something like:

```
.ui-menuitem { 
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 80px;
}
```

to the `.ui-menuitem` pf class, changing the last value (left-padding) to your needs.